# Apache authentication inside a WordPress install

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress, password-protected, .htpasswd

I am currently running into an issue with trying to password protect a directory that is sitting inside a directory that's running WordPress. This is for a directory called "admin" that handles a few things outside of WP.

In my WordPress .htaccess file, I have set a rule to ignore this directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(admin|index\.php)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

When I go to my admin directory, it works just fine and I'm able to see what I should be seeing (basic PHP stuff).

However, when I try and password protect that directory by putting an .htaccess and .htpassword file in there, I get a WordPress 404 error. This is what it looks like:

```
AuthUserFile /home/myuser/public_html/admin/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthType Basic

<limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</limit>
```

It (obviously) has something to do with the "require valid-user" line. This particular .htaccess/.htpasswd file worked just fine on a similar server set up.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A 401 error, as opposed to a 404, is what you would expect to see if the `require valid-user` line were breaking things.  Anything helpful in the Apache error log?

Comment: It specifically says 404, not 401 (but I that's coming from WordPress). And no, I don't see anything in the error log.

Comment: Working answer was posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075238/htaccess-password-protected-folder-goes-to-404-page

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your browser and then trying to connect.  You may have cached credentials that are being used.

If you have multiple secured directories with different passwords, use different values for the `Authname`.

EDIT:  Try moving the Require outside the Limit statement.  I always group the Auth definitions with the Require statement in the same block.

Your error seems to indicate the requested resource does not exist or is not readable.  Try removing your rewrite modifications for `admin`.  The standard rewrite rules work well with directories and files mixed into the Wordpress installation.

You may want to use a LimitExcept block instead of a Limit block to prevent access other than GET or POST.  This is my working .htaccess file.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /etc/wordpress/htpasswd
Require Valid-User
<LimitExcept GET POST>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

Make sure the .ht* files are readable by the web server.  I test unauthorized access by changing the user id in the `htpasswd` file to one I haven't used.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try closing the browser, but no dice. I'm not even being promoted for a user or password. Also, there is only one directly secured via .htaccess.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but still no dice. I'm thinking about try to move the admin directory outside of the web root and then just setting up a subdomain.

Comment: @Charles: You can point a subdomain directly at the admin directory.  Have you tried without the .htaccess file.  If it doesn't work without the .htaccess file then it won't work with one.  On Ubuntu the WordPress software is in /usr/share, but symlinked to /var/www for the web server to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(admin|index\.php)$ - [L]
> ```

This directive only "ignores" the URL `/admin` (no trailing slash). So, it won't exclude  requests for files inside the `/admin` subdirectory, or even the `/admin` directory itself, since mod_dir will append a slash by default via a 301 redirect, ie. `/admin/`. (On Apache 2.2, it's also likely that mod_dir is issueing an internal subrequest for the directory index, before mod_rewrite is able to process the URL. This behaviour reversed with Apache 2.4)

The mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` will then rewrite the request through WordPress. (Although you would expect any requests for physical directories/files to be ignored anyway?)

You would need to change this directive to something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(admin|index\.php$) - [L]
```

ie. Just move the `$` (end-of-string anchor) inside the parentheses. Or, create two separate directives.

Alternatively, you could simply enable (or disable) the rewrite engine inside the `/admin/.htaccess` file, in order to override the mod_rewrite directives (WordPress front-controller) in the parent `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default, so simply enabling (or disabling) the rewrite engine in a child config is enough to override the parent.